# What are the benefit of pipelines?

Tags: pipelines, cloud

I see several cloud providers offering pipeline services - GCloud with Dataflow.

I am wondering how and when to use it in an complex application architecture.

It doesn't seem adapted for serving data to a web UI because of the execution time. I could see the use for complex data processing in batch.

What are your thoughts?

Any links to online ressource would be welcome.

Thanks!